# How to set v-select value dynamically?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

My Vuetify `v-select` element looks this way:

```
<v-select
   v-bind:items="languages"
   v-model="setLocale"
   label="Language:"
   auto prepend-icon="map"
   item-value="fetchedLocale"
   hide-details
   id="langSelect"
   >
```

In `data` you can find:

```
data () {
  return {
    languages: [
      { shortCode: 'en', text: 'English' },
      { shortCode: 'pl', text: 'Polski' },
      { shortCode: 'es', text: 'Español' },
      { shortCode: 'pt', text: 'Portugues' }
    ],
    fetchedLocale: '',
    setLocale: null
  }
}, (...)
```

After some processing, `fetchedLocale` gets value of some of `text` properties from the array above, e.g. "Portugues".

Question: how to update the `v-select` so that it sets `fetchedLocale`'s value, like mentioned before "Portugues", when loading DOM elements, instead of setting default empty value?

Comment: Did you try `v-bind:item-value="fetchedLocale"`?

Comment: @Bert: yes, but with no success. Default value is displayed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[As per the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/selects), the `item-value` prop defines the property name to use as the value for each item. The default for this prop is `'value'`, meaning the `value` property of each item will be used as each item's value by default. If you set it to `text`, for example, then the `text` property of each of your `languages` will be used as the value of that item. However, this won't actually set the value of the select component.

You've already bound the value of the select component to `setLocale` via `v-model`. So if you want to change the select component's value to the `fetchedLocale` value, just update `setLocale` with the value of `fetchedLocale` and the component will update:

```
this.setLocale = this.fetchedLocale
```

Here's a working example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      languages: [
        { shortCode: 'en', text: 'English' },
        { shortCode: 'pl', text: 'Polski' },
        { shortCode: 'es', text: 'Español' },
        { shortCode: 'pt', text: 'Portugues' }
      ],
      fetchedLocale: '',
      setLocale: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.fetchedLocale = 'English';
      this.setLocale = this.fetchedLocale;
    }, 1000);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.15.7/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.15.7/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-select
      :items="languages"
      v-model="setLocale"    
      label="Language:"
      auto prepend-icon="map"
      item-value="text"
      hide-details
      id="langSelect"
    ></v-select>
  </v-app>
</div>
```